# Django + large database: how to deal with 500m rows?

Tags: django, postgresql, bigdata

I'm working on a web app with a lot of data, and would like some general tech stack advice. I'm a Django developer, but I haven't worked with this much data before.

**Apologies for the general question, but I'd really appreciate some general advice. If it's really not right for SO, rather than just voting to close it, I'd really appreciate a suggestion for a forum where I could ask for this advice.**

My database will have three tables, one of which will have approximately 500m rows (100GB of data). The data is read-only and changes infrequently, only once  a month.

The large table (500m rows) is spending items each month for the past five years, and the other tables are the institutions doing the spending (~10k rows) and the items bought (~4000 rows). The models basically look like this:

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class SpendItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Spend(models.Model):
    spend_item = models.ForeignKey(SpendingItem)
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation)
    spend_value = models.FloatField()
    processing_date = models.DateField()
```

I'll need to offer pages in the web app querying aggregating this spending data in various ways. For example, I might want to show a page per institution, with the total spend for each month, and the total spend per type of item. Or a page per item, with total spent, and spending by institution.

My initial plan was to have a Postgres back-end, since I know the shape of the data, and simply make queries through the Django ORM, or raw SQL if necessary for speed.

But I'm starting to get worried: will aggregate queries be much too slow over 500m rows? Will I need to pre-calculate all the aggregate queries? Should I also be looking into other technologies that I haven't used before, like Elasticsearch, or even BigQuery?

Another concern: is a Postgres database this size (presumably ~200GB with indexes) likely to run at an acceptable speed from an SSD, or do I need to pay for enough RAM to hold it all in memory? (Eeeek.)

I know the answer really is "try it and see", but I'd really appreciate any upfront advice from more experienced Django/Postgres/data developers. If you were working on an application this shape, how would you approach it?

Comment: what is the exact use case? what are you going to do with this data? what makes you think elasticsearch will help you?

Comment: (1) Offer information to users who are interested in how these organisations are spending, but don't have the ability to run their own 500m-row database with the raw data (the only option at the moment) (2) Create a usable web app that offers this information to those users (3) A friend said ElasticSearch helped them work with a similar web app that was essentially a front-end to a database. I might be completely wrong about it being useful in this scenario, though.

Answer (score 0):

I may **NOT** have understood the problem very clearly, but here's how i would approach it.

- I won't take the overhead of elasticsearch/solr just for calculating aggregates, (in my opinion, its useful when you want FTS, ranking and stuff)
- I would rather have an index on `processing_date` and take another two fields for `last_indexing_date` and `last_aggregate` (in each organisation maybe) and update these periodically using some background async task.
- For real time details I would just pick the `last_indexing_date` and run an aggregate for spendings beyond that date, and finally sum it up with `last_aggregate` and update these fields as well.

Not sure what you meant by:

> Create a usable web app that offers this information to those users

Hope this helps :)